# 2 dimensional List<T> in C++\CLI

Tags: c++-cli

I want to create a 2-dimensional List in C++\CLI. Question is how to declare it?

I have tried this:

```
List<List<int>^>^ H = gcnew List<List<int>>(); // Scoring matrix H
H->Add(gcnew List<int>() );

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) // Fill matrix H with 0
{
 for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
 {
 H[i]->Add(0);
 }
}
```

Then I get a lot of syntax errors, starting with this one:

error C3225: generic type argument for 'T' cannot be 'System::Collections::Generic::List', it must be a value type or a handle to a reference type

Comment: Add `using namespace System::Collections::Generic;`.  And fix your code, you'll need to add `n` lists, not just one.

Comment: Hans, good catch. Added the namespace. Updated the code before I saw your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this declaration

```
List<List<int>^>^ H = gcnew List<List<int>>();
```

The right type specifier does not correspond to the left type specifier. Should be

```
List<List<int>^>^ H = gcnew List<List<int>^>();
```

Answer (score 1):

With advice from Hans and Vlad, this seems to work:

```
List<List<int>^>^ H = gcnew List<List<int>^>(); // Scoring matrix H

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) // Fill matrix H with 0
 {
 H->Add(gcnew List<int>() );
 for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
 {
 H[i]->Add(0);
 }
}
```

Thx, Jan